# Is it possible to NOT store the folder structure when creating a zip with the package class?

Tags: c#, system.io.packaging

I'm using the Package class to create a zip file. This works quite fine.
The only thing I don't want to have there (which exists) is: The folder structure is also saved. Despite looking through the class I found no parameter there so I fear it is not possible, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

My question thus is: Is there any way to NOT save the folder structure into the .zip file?

***Example***:
`c:\test\mytest\blahblup.txt`   should be stored as  `blahblup.txt` instead of `c:\test\mytest\blahblup.txt` inside the .zip file.

***Code used:***

```
        using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Package zipPackage = Package.Open(zipStream, FileMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (string fileName in FilesInFolderArray)
                {
                    string relativerfileName = regexLaufwerk.Replace(fileName, string.Empty).Replace(@"\", @"/");
                    PackagePart zipPartPackage = zipPackage.CreatePart(new Uri(relativerfileName, UriKind.Relative), "", CompressionOption.Maximum);

                    using (FileStream originalFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipPartPackage.GetStream());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Store all files in a temp folder, and zip the contents of that.

Comment: is there any other optoin there? (the machine I have to use the program on has quite a low free space count and storing those files in the temp folder could stretch that free space quite a lot :/ )

Comment: So you want to *flatten* the folder structure before zipping. What files with identical names?

Comment: @Thomas *why* do you want to flatten the hierarchy? If there are so many files that you have space issues, the resulting zip file will be simply unmanageable.

Comment: In any case it's your code that generates the stored files's name. Why don't you simply extract the file's name with `Path.GetFileName`? Most likely the regular expression you used (but didn't post here) fails to process the file path

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm creating the .zip file to transmit a few log files (unique names) and the request to flatten it came from the receiving side. 
does the uri in .CreatePart not have to point to an existing file? (if not then I had misunderstood it and can change that to just the filename)

Comment: @Thomas, no it doesn't - you are copying the actual contents with `CopyTo`.  In fact the Packaging API is very low-level API - you can create any part with any content and name that you want. For example, Office stores stylesheets, references etc as separate parts that would appear as separate files if you unzipped an `xlsx` file.

Comment: ah ok that means I just need to put JUST the filename into the new Uri command and I get the desired result.  tnx!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your idea with the uri which only has the filename instead of the full path in it just does the intended job. do you want to post the answer there?